# Image processing filters

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am implementing the Box filter and I wonder if I should allow
filter mask sizes like 3 X 5 or whatever, where the width is different
than the height.

So far I have implemented only filters with mask sizes like 3x3 or 5x5.
Is it valid to allow width to be different than height? I guess I could 
allow the user to specify such mask but if he gets wierd results it is his
fault?

Thanks

Comment: This question belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid.

Filters can be different in the different dimensions. This can happen in optics too, if the lens you are using is not uniform around the center.

Answer (score 0):

A **box filter** is traditionally implemented as `N x N`, but you can change this to whatever you like.

Just a side note, OpenCV let's you [create your own filters with `cv::filter2D()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) but the function doesn't allow you to create non-quadratic filters. However, [`cv::blur()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-blur) which is a box filter, let's you to pass `N x M` sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your application requires repeated box-filtering of the **same** image with multiple box filters of different sizes, it is much more efficient to first compute the integral of the given image (which is O(N), in the number N of pixels), and then compute each filter's output from the integral (again in O(N)). For m filters this gives an m * O(N) algorithm regardless of the box sizes. If you are filtering with several large boxes this is normally a big performance win.

See [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-integral) for the OpenCV implementation.